# Is there a relation between Cartesian and tensor product of function spaces and function factorizability

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

**H1** and **H2** are two Hilbert spaces represented by a function space, say **f1(x1)** and **f2(x2)** are its vectors. If **H3** is tensor product of **H1** and **H2** I assume one can say that **f(x1,x2)** now represents vectors in **H3**.

The scalar product for **f(x1,x2)** would be a tensor scalar product.

Now say that **f(x1,x2)** can be factorized into **f1(x1)f2(x2)**.

Does that mean that this vector is in the Cartesian product subspace of the tensor product space and that scalar product of **f1(x1)f2(x2)** would be identical to a scalar product as calculated for Cartesian product spaces?

Edit: I am not even sure that the concept of Cartesian product subspace of the tensor product space makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: I am not even sure that the concept of Cartesian product subspace of the tensor product space makes sense.

Let's start with this bit. Given vector spaces (or Hilbert spaces) $V$ and $W$ there's a canonical map $V\times W \rightarrow V \otimes W$. But this isn't a linear map, and its image isn't a subspace. But its image is still a subset, which we call the set of simple tensors.

> **H1** and **H2** are two Hilbert spaces represented by a function space, say **f1(x1)** and **f2(x2)** are its vectors. If **H3** is tensor product of **H1** and **H2** I assume one can say that **f(x1,x2)** now represents vectors in **H3**.
>
> The scalar product for **f(x1,x2)** would be a tensor scalar product.
>
> Now say that **f(x1,x2)** can be factorized into **f1(x1)f2(x2)**.
>
> Does that mean that this vector is in the Cartesian product subspace of the tensor product space and that scalar product of **f1(x1)f2(x2)** would be identical to a scalar product as calculated for Cartesian product spaces?

This bit is all exactly right. A function $f(x_1,x_2)$ can be factored as $f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)$ if and only if it lies in the image of the Cartesian product under the above map. That is to say the simple tensors are precisely the ones that factor.

Comment: before I accept the answer, could you, please, point me to a book or online reference where this is a bit more elaborated, hopefully with examples? I googled a lot but could never find anything on this.

Comment: Especially the scalar product. I have been unable to see how tensor scalar product, in the case of simple tensors, ends up looking like the Cartesian scalar product.